# Is Parallel Kernel Status Monitor available on Raspberry Pi?

Tags: parallelization, raspberry-pi, menu

I have used the Parallel Kernel Status Monitor documented here

https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ParallelTools/tutorial/ConfiguringAndMonitoring.html

on a machine running, I think, version 9 of Mathematica.

Now I am using Mathematica v. 10.3.1.0 on a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B and I can't find the parallel kernel status monitor.

In the Evaluation menu I have "Kernel Configuration Options", but this leads to a dialogue box for adding, removing or editing the properties of kernels.

Comment: Does evaluating ``Parallel`Palette`menuStatus[]`` open the Parallel Kernel Status Monitor on your Raspberry Pi?

Comment: Yes it does ! Thank you very much ! Would you care to make this an answer so that I can accept it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Running on a Raspberry Pi 3 ...

```
ParallelEvaluate[$KernelID]
```

> {1,2,3,4}

[image]

The following launches the Parallel Kernel Status window and runs a simple evaluation that utilizes 100% of the proccesor's 4 cores:

```
Parallel`Palette`menuStatus[]
ParallelEvaluate[Timing[Inverse[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {1000, 1000}]];
```

> {{21.62, Null}, {21.94, Null}, {22.67, Null}, {22.54, Null}}

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much ! That worked for me. The red "busy" indicators light up but unfortunately the green "Performance Measurements" bars do not light up, and the "Time Elapsed" reading remains at 0.000, and the "speedup" at n/a. Do I understand correctly from your picture above that the same happened for you ?

Comment: @Simon It seemed erratic. I know at least once it showed "Time Elapsed".

Comment: Thank you very much Young and @Karsten 7.